# Problem exporting module in node: functions not exported correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module that has an index.js file and 2 different utility files with functions.

Index has:

```
const utl = require('./tools');
const updt = require('./update');
```

While both files have a version of (this is the update.js exports):

```
module.exports = { 
    updateResults, 
    addTeamIDsToArray, 
    updateTeamStats,
    retrieveRankings, 
    numbOfWeeksToToday }
```

And the tools.js exports:

```
   module.exports = {
    add_weeks,
    format_date,
    waitForMe, 
    chooseWinner
    }
```

However, when I check both constants in my index.js file, one of them is empty:

```
    console.log(updt)
    console.log(utl)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    {}
    {
      add_weeks: [Function: add_weeks],
      format_date: [Function: format_date],
      waitForMe: [Function: waitForMe],
      chooseWinner: [Function: chooseWinner]
    }
```

Why is my update file not exporting correctly?

Comment: Circular dependencies maybe?

Comment: Maybe. Update uses Tools to work, and it might have been the problem if the Tools import wasn't working inside Update, and therefore breaking the functions there, but there were no errors.

Comment: Was update importing the tools from `./tools` or from `.` (`index.js`)?

Comment: Directly from ./tools. Is that poor form?

Comment: Nah, that should work then, unless `tools.js` imports `./update` or `./index`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I still don't know how this got fixed but if it ever props back I will updated this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean both files have the same `module.exports` ?

<s>It's impossible to answer this question without seeing whats in the "tools" directory, as it seems to be behaving correctly; returing an object of the contents exported from the file- in this case, an empty object.</s> *(Reason: OP added details)*

If it's any consolation, I think you're doing this correct overall. This leads me to wonder a few things!

- Have you tried changing the file name?
- Using different import methods? (ESM `import x from "x"` / `await import("x")`)
- Create some object random object (we'll call it `obj = { updateResults, addTeamIDsToArray, ...}`), add all the exported items, then `module.exports = obj`?
- Destructuring the import to further debug? Ex: `const { updateResults } = reqiure("./tools")` ?
- Obvious but made sure the relative path `"./tools"` is correct?

These are just a few things to check or try out, just to check.

And last but not least, good ole' turn it off and back on again just to be sure we cover it all.

Comment: Added that to my post. I'm confused because everything seems the same, not sure what could be the bug.

Comment: Well, wouldn't you know it, not sure what happened but it is fixed now... Not sure what did it tbh, but I couldn't have done it without your requests for additional info + all of the really good ideas you suggested. Thanks =)